# How to add a Button as a child of a DrawingVisual

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DerivedCanvas class which inherits from Canvas. I use it to draw several custom drawing visuals, but can't figure out how to add a Button object as a child of a DrawingVisual object. Below is the code I am using within the DrawingVisual, but nothing shows up at runtime. Is it not possible to add a Button as a child of a DrawingVisual, or am I just doing it wrong?

```
Button button = new Button { Content = "Exit", Width = 70, Height = 23 };
this.Children.Add(button);
```

Comment: I have done this very thing and had it work. I derived from Control, however, so that could make a difference. Also, at what time are you adding the child control?

Comment: Great! At least I know it's possible! I have added the child control both before the parent visual is drawn, and after, but neither worked. Would it be possible to share your code?

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that your code is executed? Place a breakpoint. Also "this" might nor refer to the object you want..

Comment: I have added a breakpoint and the code is executed. Further, the number of children 'this' has is increased by one. 'this' does refer to the object I want, but still nothing is drawn on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming that `dv` is your `DrawingVisual` object and `size` is the size of `dv`):

```
foreach (var child in dv.Children)
{
    var element = child as UIElement;
    if (element == null) continue;
    element.Arrange(new Rect(size));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Add try-catch to handle exception.
2.I guess button has created and added.But coordinate is out of visual range.You should alter coordinate of the button and refresh.